# plot(dcc.fit) returns no output

Tags: r

```
> dput(MSFT.GSPC.ret[1:20,])
structure(c(-0.0343636188400374, 0.0104885242596549, -0.0340719994524541, 
0.0129834504230537, 0.00726425460144453, -0.0259456191414236, 
-0.0331137622240925, 0.0187248508043534, 0.0403345305611627, 
0.0269175013880338, -0.0748170288918457, -0.0093898221229205, 
-0.0214547692070148, -0.0243910256435065, 0.0153138591890918, 
-0.0340067862273159, -0.00630881036315545, -0.00507636532488531, 
-0.00382393403377179, 0.0504309696315595, -0.0390991755058661, 
0.00192033767176891, 0.000955221868328415, 0.0267299500582903, 
0.0111278249512576, -0.0131485767905737, -0.00439601996101047, 
0.0120962453648144, 0.0106147630153357, -0.0068555164525268, 
0.000522156347618541, -0.00712061248542284, -0.00291656817789931, 
-0.0280225841963713, 0.00604648360431792, -0.00422161942814814, 
-0.00394620386197975, -0.0278408131523173, 0.0249048507060516, 
0.0105717406599295), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1512141560.23421, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), ret_type = "log", index = structure(c(946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 947548800, 947635200, 
947721600, 947808000, 948153600, 948240000, 948326400, 948412800, 
948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 948931200, 949017600, 949276800, 
949363200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(20L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("MSFT", "GSPC")))
```

I am using Rstudio with Rversion 3.4.2

I'm using rugarch and rmgarch to spec and fit model with DCC to my data. The model is generated successfully, however I'm unable to generate the plots. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
# univariate normal GARCH(1,1) for each series
garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), 
                          variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                          model = "sGARCH"), 
                          distribution.model = "norm")

# dcc specification - GARCH(1,1) for conditional correlations
dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(2, garch11.spec) ), 
                           dccOrder = c(1,1), 
                           distribution = "mvnorm")
dcc.garch11.spec

dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = MSFT.GSPC.ret)
class(dcc.fit)
slotNames(dcc.fit)
names(dcc.fit@mfit)
names(dcc.fit@model)

# many extractor functions - see help on DCCfit object
# coef, likelihood, rshape, rskew, fitted, sigma, 
# residuals, plot, infocriteria, rcor, rcov
# show, nisurface

# show dcc fit
dcc.fit

# plot method
plot(dcc.fit)
# Make a plot selection (or 0 to exit): 
#   
# 1:   Conditional Mean (vs Realized Returns)
# 2:   Conditional Sigma (vs Realized Absolute Returns)
# 3:   Conditional Covariance
# 4:   Conditional Correlation
# 5:   EW Portfolio Plot with conditional density VaR limits
```

It does not matter which one I select, I get this output which is non-existent:

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngjjp.png)

However, if I leave by selecting 0, then I get the following warnings:

```
Selection: 0
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(c(946944000, 1333324800), c(0.000429087998147139,  ... :
  relative range of values =  37 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
2: In plot.window(c(946944000, 1333324800), c(0.000429087998147139,  ... :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
3: In plot.window(c(946944000, 1333324800), c(0.000429087998147139,  ... :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  37 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
6: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
7: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  37 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
8: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
9: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
10: In plot.window(c(946944000, 1333324800), c(0.000429087998147139,  ... :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
11: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  37 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
12: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
13: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
14: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
15: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  37 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
16: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
17: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
18: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  relative range of values =  32 * EPS, is small (axis 2)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(MSFT.GSPC.ret)` ? A subset would be ok.

Comment: Didn't work, output too long:

I have a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/4uttPnB.png

Comment: And what about `dput(MSFT.GSPC.ret[1:20,])` ? Do not post image of your data.

Comment: @MarcoSandri ; See post, I have edited it! It worked.